# Unable to make jqGrid to work for composite key

Tags: jqgrid

I still have problem defining composite key in jqGrid. Even though I set the 3 fields that are the composite key with attribute 'editable: true', the jqGrid does not behave correctly. I haven't used any 'key=true' in any of the fields as the jqGrid document mentions it that not more than one field can use this attribute. When I point to one of the rows in the List View, jqGrid high lights two rows, instead of one row. Is there any other attribute I need to use to specify more than one field for the composite key.

Comment: Please share your code for anyone to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The usage of composite key is very easy. The property `id` if input items is used by default as the key (rowid). Thus you need just fill the input data with `id` properties, which constructed from the 3 fields and some separator, like `_` for example, which is not a part of the field. If you will have some implementation problems, then you need just include an example of input data and the composite key, which you want to have.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you for your response. Could you give me an example? Where should I place this code ? Does this code go to the "colMode" area ? I am reading the data from a Java controller. A quick example would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Oleg again, From what you mentioned, something came to my mind. I just set the 'id' property to concatination of the 3 fields in the  'jsonReader' section. This fixed the issue. Is this what you were referring to ?

Comment: @jnem: *You* should post your code and with an example of input data, which you use to fill the grid. You should additional include always *the version* of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and *the fork* ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). There are too many options to fill (local data, JSON, XML data, `loadonce: true`, ...) the grid and too many different variants of the grid (data grouping, TreeGrid, subgrids and so on).

Comment: @jnem: I wrote already that  "you need just include an example of input data and the composite key, which you want to have*. If you assign any value to `id` property, then the value will be used as rowid. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). Thus you probably need only extend *your server code* and assign one more property. Alternatively, in case of loading from the server and you are unable to change server data, you can use `beforeProcessing` callback to fill composite `id` key.